# redefining \index

Tags: indexing

I use several indices, e.g. 'names', 'subject' doing this with entries of the form 
`\index{names}{Columbus}`. These indices are created with the `multind` package.

Unfortunately some of the tex files have index commands of the form `\index{Columbus}`.  I do not want to have to go through all of these files and replace `\index{Columbus}` with `\index{names}{Columbus}`.

Can I redefine `\index` to point to the correct index file?, i.e. from `myfile.ind` to `names.ind`

Comment: `\let\oldindex\index\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\index{names}{#1}}` should work; it'd be great if you could provide us with a complete MWE to play with and test

Comment: it's probably not helpful for this round, but for future documents, you should look into the `imakeidx` package.  it uses the `[...]` optional notation to distinguish "other" indexes, so the basic index doesn't have to be specified.  (there are other advantages as well, but that's perhaps the most obvious.)

Comment: @cmhughes: I think this is going to need `xparse` as the OP wants `\index{Columbus}` to be the same as `\index{names}{Columbus}`. That is an _optional_ parameter but using `{}`.  And yes it would it would be very helpful if we had a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up a test case for the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax `\index{names}{Columbus}` and `\index{Columbus}` is ambigous, because the latter form could be followed by another curly braces group, e.g:

```
\index{abc}{xyz}
```

Is `abc` the register with entry `xyz` or is `abc` the name for the name register?

There are several ways to deal with the ambiguity:

- `\index` could check, whether the first argument is a known register name and uses then the two argument form.

  Restrictions: `\index` must know all registers and the register name must not appear as entry.
- `\index` could read the first argument and check the next token. If an opening curly brace follows, use the two argument form, otherwise the first argument is already the name for the name register.

  Restrictions: An opening curly brace must not follow the one-argument form.

The example below implements the latter case.
`\index` is a little tricky`:

- The entry argument is read verbatim with changed category codes to prevent the premature expansion. Rather the argument should go unmodified into the `.idx` file.
- `\index` tries to be invisble by looking for spaces before and after. It ignores a following space, if it has detected a previous. Therefore the code is surrounded by `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack`. In this case the commands of the original `\index` will continue to work, because the original `\index` is called after the argument checking.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multind}% Caution: old LaTeX 2.09 package
% Better alternatives:
% imakeidx: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx
% index: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/index

\makeindex{names}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\org@index}{}
\let\org@index\index
\newcommand*{\index@param}{}
\renewcommand*{\index}{%
  \begingroup % limit the scope for verbatim category codes
  \@sanitize % verbatim category codes
  \index@i
}
\newcommand*{\index@i}[1]{%
  \gdef\index@param{#1}% remember the first argument in global macro
  \endgroup
  \futurelet\@let@token\index@ii % peek at next token
}
\newcommand*{\index@ii}{%
  \ifx\@let@token\bgroup
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {%
    \org@index{\index@param}%
  }{%
    \org@index{names}{\index@param}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\index{names}{Columbus}

\index{Knuth}

% Test spaces
[ \index{test} ][\index{test} ][ \index{test}][\index{test}]

\printindex{names}{Name register}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Name register]